# How do to access files using folder Id

Tags: google-drive-api

Just having a difficult time figuring how to access files in folders using Googles Drive RESP API v3.

I know I can access files using the `/children` in v2 of REST API

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/folderId/children
```

According to [migration notes](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration) for v3 of REST API

> Duplicate and obsolete functionality has been removed. Examples:
>
> - The Children and Parents collections have been removed. Use files.list instead.

From what I can gather `children.list` was a function you could leverage if you used `gapi.js`

```
request = gapi.client.drive.children.list({
  'folderId' : folderId,
  'pageToken': nextPageToken
});
```

Again, following the notes `children.list` should be substituted for `files.list with ?q='parent_id'+in+parents`.

But what does that actually mean for REST API users?

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q={folderId}+in+parents
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=parents(folderId)
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=folderId
```

No matter what I try I just keep getting 400 error - invalid value in the q.

References:

- [Google Drive REST API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk)
- [Google Drive REST API v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/about-sdk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification?

I don't know whether I can understand your question. If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

I think that `q='parent_id'+in+parents` you use is correct. It means that a file list in the `parent_id` is retrieved. But when I see your tested endpoint and query, there is a modification point that I thought that this might be the reason of error.

### From :

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q={folderId}+in+parents
```

### To :

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q='{folderId}'+in+parents
```

#### About error message :

When I tried to run it without the single quotes, the following error was retrieved. So I thought that this might be the reason.

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid Value",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "q"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid Value"
 }
}
```

### Reference :

- https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters#examples
- If you want to test, you can do it [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list).

If you have already used the single quotes in `{folderId}`, and if this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the examples page. I was hard pressed finding some examples on Friday. Turns out the issue was with ``+`` sign in the q input ``'{folderid}'+in+parents``. As per my observation this morning if you replace ``+`` with ``space`` you get expected response otherwise you get the above error. And as per examples page, the example provided also uses spaces ``'1234567' in parents``.

Comment: @iiminov I'm glad I could help you. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 1):

The format is

> https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=%270Bw3h_yCVtXbbQ2VEQkRNQ0J1YTg%27%20in%20parents

Note the single quote (%27) around the folder ID.

Comment: That certainly did the trick. I could have sworn I tried both single and double quotes before which gave me errors. What actually made the difference is ``%20`` which is a ``space``. On the website If you input q as ``'{folderid}'+in+parents`` you get 400 error but if you input ``'{folderid}' in parents`` you get expected results. But if you make an actual request from a javascript application/code both forms work. Go figure.